Search box loses focuses while typing when searching the current webpage with Safari for macOS
I am talking about the search box for searching the current webpage:

For me, this search box very regularly loses its focus while I am typing search terms, requiring me to press the shortcut again to continue typing.
Using macOS 15.0 and Safari 18.0 with several extensions (which I could disable step-by-step if nothing else).
